# Send play/pause command c++

Tags: c++, arduino, keyboard-shortcuts, audio-player, infrared

So I'm trying to control my computer with an IR remote control. I get the IR code thanks to an arduino nano which sends it to my computer by the serial port.

I want to, for example depending on the code sent, send a play or pause or next and so on command to spotify or win media player or any other app.

I know that you have keyboards shortcuts for this so my question is how do I reproduce the commands that these keyboards shortcuts send to all the programs to stop the music ?

Thanks in advance for any help ! :)

Comment: You might want to look into winapi since you seem to be targetting windows.

Comment: https://github.com/NicoHood/HID

Comment: @Asu Thank you do you know if there are anything faster to code ? Or do I have to really dive in those API and documentations ? aha

Comment: @gre_gor thank you ! Do you know if this works with an Arduino Nano (ATmega328) because I always get this error
`C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HID-master\src/HID-Project.h:35:2: error: #error HID Project can only be used with an USB MCU.

#error HID Project can only be used with an USB MCU.`

Comment: Unfortunately Nano doesn't have an ATmega16u2, that is needed for a board with ATmega328, like an Uno or a Mega to work with NicoHood. Instead, Nano has a FTDI chip or a CH340G, which can not be reprogrammed. I would recommend you use a board with a MCU with native USB support (ATmega32u4) like a [Leonardo](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/arduinoBoardLeonardo), [Micro](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMicro) or a [Pro Micro](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640). You can get a Pro Micro from China for $3.

Comment: @gre_gor thank you !